# PopupWindow press back button to do the action

Tags: java, android, back

I have a `Activity` and implement `PopupWindow` class for a apps alert view.
My excepted case is the popupwindow is shown and pressed the device back button that will be called another action.
I tried to implement the `onBackPressed` in my Activity. But the popupwindow is shown, `onBackPressed` won't call. When I dismissed the popupwindow, the `onBackPressed` is called.
So anyone know how can implement the back button method in my case. Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Popup window is a fragment or what?

Comment: @Abdul `android.widget.PopupWindow`

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818297/onbackpressed-not-called-when-popupwindow-is-showing this one?

Comment: do you mean this solution?`popWindow.setFocusable(true);` Yes I already set true

Comment: what about creating a global reference and then you check if the alert is shown. If it is there then dismiss it and call the action.

Comment: At the url that I mentioned, it says that you should remove the ```popWindow.setFocusable(true)``` and ```final PopupWindow popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x, size.y, false);``` do it like this way

Comment: @Abdul my action is need to press the back button if the popupwindow is shown. But the onBackPressed not called now. So this way is not suitable for me.

Comment: what about alert.setOnDismissListener ?

Comment: @Abdul I tried this listener. But I don't know why not call when the popupwindow is dismissed

Comment: @LeeWonJoong You right!! I removed the `setFcusable(true)`. The `onBackPressed` will be called. Thanks

Comment: @WongManlok Great, if it's okay could you select my answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `popWindow.setFocusable(true)` this part.

And set `final PopupWindow popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x, size.y, false);` like this.

If you want to see more detail of the answer, you could also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818297/onbackpressed-not-called-when-popupwindow-is-showing).